# How to call non static methods in java

Tags: java, methods, call

I have two non-static methods which I want to call in a new method. How do i do this ?

I have tried .methodName() but when I try to compile I receive an error message  saying "cannot find symbol - method methodName()"

Comment: You need an `instance` of the `class` in which the method is defined, so long as you can see the `access modifiers` which define it from the calling method.

Comment: Duplicate of [Example of an instance method? (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033673/example-of-an-instance-method-java). OP you really need to start with a basic java tutorial or book, this is very basic stuff that you need to teach yourself first.

Comment: please go read a java fundamental book

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestClass {


    public String firstMethod()
    {
        return "first Method";
    }

    public String secondMethod()
    {
        return "Second Method";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestClass object = new TestClass(); // create a object for class `TestClass`
        System.out.println(object.firstMethod()); // access the non-static method by `classname.methodName` 
        System.out.println(object.secondMethod());          
    }

}
```

Output :

```
first Method
Second Method
```